# Why is division used for "discounting" in DCF?

Tags: discounting

In DCF analysis the formula for representing a cash flow in period n is denoted D<sub>n</sub> and letting the risk free rate opportunity cost to be r<sub>n</sub> we can represent the discounted cash flow as

D<sub>n</sub> / (1 + r<sub>n</sub>)<sup>n</sup>

My question is: what is the logic in using division to discount the cash flow?

Comment: "*and not some other arbitrary operation*"????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operation is by no means arbitrary. It's a reversal of the *future value* formula used to calculate compounded returns.

Suppose you have a bank account that pays 1% per year. You deposit $100 in that account.  In one year you'll earn $1 (1% of $100) in interest, so mathematically your value after one year is:

```
100 + (100 * .01) = 100 * (1.01) = 101
```

or generically

```
P1 = P0 * (1+r)
```

after two years, you'll earn *another* 1% of the $101, so you'll have

```
101 + (101 * 0.01) = 101 * (1.01) = 102.01
```

or generically

```
P2 = P1 * (1+r) = P0 * (1+r) * (1+r) = P0 * (1+r)^2
```

Continuing the pattern, after `n` years you'll have

```
Pn = P0 * (1+r)^n
```

So now think about "discounting" as "how much could I invest now (`D0`) at a rate of `r` to end up with `Dn` after `n` years?"

The formula would be:

```
Dn = D0 * (1+r)^n
```

solving for `D0`, you get

```
D0 = Dn / (1+r)^n
```

(this example uses a constant interest rate `r` - in your question you allow for different "interest rates" per cash flow, so you'd use `r(n)`)